# What does 'value type that is initialized to all 0's' mean?

Tags: c#, initialization

I am wondering about a sentence in a book about C# I'm reading currently. This sentence is:

> 'value type that is initialized to all 0's'.

Probably I don't understand it because I'm not a native speaker.

In my understanding of the language would that mean that a variable has multiple values when it gets initialized? This doesn't really makes sense to me. Could you help me to understand what this means?

Answer (score 4):

Consider this value type:

```
public struct Point
{
   public int X;
   public int Y;
}
```

"All 0's" here means X = 0 and Y = 0.

**Update:** I just discovered that this example is used in the [MSDN documentation for struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). They throw in a constructor.

Comment: I think this response is somewhat imprecise. Zero in memory does not necessarily *mean* "zero", as it happens to do for `int` variables. The sentence in the book, however, probably refers to zeroes in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence is not correctly formulated.
I guess that the author means, or should have written, that a value type is initialized to its default value when it is declared.
In case of an integer (which is a value type), the default value is 0.

For instance

```
public struct Test
{
   public int a;
   public Decimal b;
   public DateTime c;

   public void Output(){

      Console.WriteLine ("a: " + a);
      Console.WriteLine ("b: " + b);
      Console.WriteLine ("c: " + c);

   }
}

var t = new Test();
t.Output();
```

will display:

```
a: 0
b: 0
c: 01/01/0001 0:00:00
```

Comment: This only applies to fields, not locals. Also, reference types are default-initialized as well.

Comment: The sentence is correct, as the underlying value in memory (in the case of `DateTime`, ticks since the date shown as value `c`) would be zero. +1 for showing `DateTime` as an example where the memory value is indeed 0, even though it does not *represent* a value that we would interpret as "zero".

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is about *default values* of value types like `byte`, `double`, `int`, `sbyte`, `short`, `uint`, `ushort`, `ulong`.

For example when you say this;

```
int i = new int();
```

`i` initialized to `0.`

Check [`Default Values Table (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Also it could be using value types in a struct type like;

```
public struct MyStruct
{
   public int X;
   public short Y;
   public double Z;
}
```

The values of `X`, `Y` and `Z` are `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably author means *default* value for every type present inside the value type instance (which is naturally might be different for every type).

To achieve this you can do like:

```
MyStruct struc = default(MyStruct);
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable of a value type occupies a certain number of bytes in memory. The statement that this type is initialized to zeroes means that all of these bytes are set to the value *0* upon initialization of the variable.

This seems to be true for many, if not all, value types (i.e. primitive number types, structs, ...), as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567726/net-value-type-initialization).

Answer (score 0):

A value type is a non-reference type, such as a struct or integer. By saying it "initializes to all zeroes" it means that if you don't set it to something it will be auto-initialized to the zero value.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int  _foo;
    public int? _bar;

    public void Output()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this._foo); // Outputs: 0
        Console.WriteLine(this._bar.HasValue ? "not null" : "null"); // Outputs: null
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont forget this is false for `int?(Nullable<T>)`. I mean which will have null as default

Comment: Yes. Nullables are reference types since they box value types.

Comment: @NickGotch: [The answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149173/are-nullable-types-reference-types) come to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Makes sense.

Comment: @NickGotch your assumption is wrong. it is actually a struct. which has a Boolean saying `HasValue`, setting it to null just makes this Boolean to false. It is actually a `Struct` compiler pretends to show as null.

Comment: So the reason a Nullable would default to zero would be because if everything is initialized to zero, the HasValue would default to false and make it act as a null. Good to know.